# Proper msg display

Tags: java

I don't get any errors but I want to display this msg "No discount. Your total is $*_*"
using this code:

```
if (!(sales < 10))
            System.out.print("No discount. " + 
                             "Your total is: $" + (int)total);
```

inside this code:

```
if (!(sales < 10))
                System.out.print("No discount. " + 
                                 "Your total is: $" + (int)total);
            else if (sales >= 10 || sales <= 19)  
                rate = 0.20;  
            else if (sales >= 20 || sales <=49)  
                rate = 0.30;  
            else if (sales >= 50 || sales <=99)  
                rate = 0.40;  
            else if (sales > 100)  
                rate = 0.50;  
            else
                System.out.println("Your discount is $" + (int)discount + 
                                   ". Your total is: $" + (int)total);
```

and it does show but i only want it to show when **sales< 10**

but if **sales is NOT < 10** then i want it to show **"Your discount is $*_*__. Your total is $*_*___."**

any help will be very much appreciated. thanks for your time.

whole code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SoftwareSales
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      int sales = 99;

      int quantity;
      double total;
      double rate = 0;
      double discount;

      System.out.print ("Enter amount of packages purchased: ");
            quantity = keyboard.nextInt();

      total = quantity * sales;
      discount = total * rate;
      total = total - discount;

      if (sales < 10) {
            if (sales >= 10 || sales <= 19)  
                rate = 0.20;  
            else if (sales >= 20 || sales <=49)  
                rate = 0.30;  
            else if (sales >= 50 || sales <=99)  
                rate = 0.40;  
            else if (sales > 100)  
                rate = 0.50;  
            System.out.println("Your discount is $" + (int)discount + 
                                   ". Your total is: $" + (int)total);
      } else {

                System.out.print("No discount. " + 
                                 "Your total is: $" + (int)total);
}
   }
}
```

Comment: Please use `{}` around blocks.

Comment: In your `if-else` blocks. Don't using `{}` leads to errors.

Comment: it already has `{}` around that block

Comment: No, use `{}` around *each* `if`, `else if`, and `else`.

Comment: Can you edit my code to show me what you are talking about? sorry if im not getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (sales > 10) {
    if (sales >= 10 || sales <= 19)  
        rate = 0.20;  
    else if (sales >= 20 || sales <=49)  
        rate = 0.30;  
    else if (sales >= 50 || sales <=99)  
        rate = 0.40;  
    else if (sales > 100)  
        rate = 0.50;  
    System.out.println("Your discount is $" + (int)discount + 
                                   ". Your total is: $" + (int)total);
} else {

    System.out.print("No discount. " + 
                                 "Your total is: $" + (int)total);
}
```

Comment: You are the only correct answer, Just the `else if`, I resolved it, vote up :)

Comment: I get an error code saying _"else with out if" for this line:

`else if (sales >= 10 || sales <= 19)  
                rate = 0.20;`

but if i take it for all it gives me more errors @JunedAhsan

Comment: @user2771077 check it now

Comment: it still only displays the **"no discount"** but it does show the calculations for the total.

Comment: @user2771077 it will dispaly "no discount" in case when sales <=10. Otherwise it will show "your discount..."

Comment: yeah but when i enter anything above 10 it still says "no discount" @JunedAhsan

Comment: @user2771077 You are typing `if (sales < 10)`, the solution is `if (sales > 10)`

Comment: Im checking if sales is less then 10 i want it to display **"No discount. Your total is ___"** and when its 10 or above to display **"Your discount is $____. Your total is $____"** but i put any number and it still says **"no discount"** @fujy

Comment: @user2771077 You need to change       if (sales < 10) {
to       if (sales > 10) {

Answer (score 1):

So why are you testing for the exact *opposite* of what you want to do? Notice the exclamation mark (`!`) which inverts your sales test in your first if. Remove that and your code should work as intended.